# Python Application failing in Openshift Pipeline: Terminated due to signal 9

Tags: python, dockerfile, openshift, gunicorn

We have a Python application that is failing to deploy in Openshift.

This is the only logs that we can gather looking at the logs in the pod.

```
[2021-08-11 18:59:01 +0000] [2184] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 2184
[2021-08-11 18:59:01 +0000] [1475] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 1475)
[2021-08-11 18:59:01 +0000] [1] [WARNING] Worker with pid 1471 was terminated due to signal 9
[2021-08-11 18:59:01 +0000] [1474] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
```

Through some research, we thought it might be a memory issue so we increased the memory usage, but it's still failing. Currently, reaching out to our DevOps team to assist but figured I would ask in the meantime.

I apologize if this may not provide enough information. This is pretty much all the information I could gather. I can try to provide additional information, if needed.

Thank you in advance!

EDIT 1:

**config.py**

```
import os
import json
import re

workers = int(os.environ.get('GUNICORN_PROCESSES', '1'))
threads = int(os.environ.get('GUNICORN_THREADS', '1'))
timeout = 10000

def pre_request(worker, req):
    worker.log.debug("pre-request works")
    
    worker.log.debug
    if req.path == '/healthcheck':
        return
    worker.log.info("%s %s" % (req.method, req.path))

forwarded_allow_ips = '*'
secure_scheme_headers = { 'X-Forwarded-Proto': 'https' }
```

**wsgi.py**

```
import logging

from paf.service.metar.metar_service import MetarService
log = logging.getLogger('werkzeug')
log.disabled = True
application = Flask(__name__)
application.logger.disabled = True
health = HealthCheck()
environment = Environment(print_environment=True)

def pre_request(worker, req):
    if req.path == '/healthcheck':
        return
    worker.log.debug("%s %s" % (req.method, req.path))
```

**Jenkinsfile**

```
// Use UPS OpenShift CI shared library 
@Library('openshift-ci@master') _

runGitFlow {
    name = "python-service"
    app = "app"
    contextDir = "/"
    ocpTemplate = "python-service-template.yml"
    buildProjectConfig = [
            NUM_REPLICAS       : 1,
            BUILD_CPU_REQUEST  : "100m",
            BUILD_CPU_LIMIT    : "1",
            BUILD_MEM_REQUEST  : "500Mi",
            BUILD_MEM_LIMIT    : "3Gi",
            DEPLOY_CPU_REQUEST : "100m",
            DEPLOY_CPU_LIMIT   : "1",
            DEPLOY_MEM_REQUEST : "500Mi",
            DEPLOY_MEM_LIMIT   : "2Gi",
            READINESS_DELAY    : 30,
            LIVENESS_DELAY     : 30,
            CONFIG_MAP_OPTIONAL: true,
            SECRET_OPTIONAL    : true
    ]
    integrationProjectConfig = [
            NUM_REPLICAS      : 1,
            DEPLOY_CPU_REQUEST: "100m",
            DEPLOY_CPU_LIMIT  : "1",
            DEPLOY_MEM_REQUEST: "2Gi",
            DEPLOY_MEM_LIMIT  : "2Gi",
            READINESS_DELAY   : 30,
            LIVENESS_DELAY    : 30,
            CONFIG_MAP_OPTIONAL: true,
            SECRET_OPTIONAL    : true
    ]
    acceptanceProjectConfig = [
            NUM_REPLICAS      : 1,
            DEPLOY_CPU_REQUEST: "100m",
            DEPLOY_CPU_LIMIT  : "100m",
            DEPLOY_MEM_REQUEST: "500Mi",
            DEPLOY_MEM_LIMIT  : "500Mi",
            READINESS_DELAY   : 30,
            LIVENESS_DELAY    : 360,
    ]
    stressProjectConfig = [
            NUM_REPLICAS      : 1,
            DEPLOY_CPU_REQUEST: "100m",
            DEPLOY_CPU_LIMIT  : "100m",
            DEPLOY_MEM_REQUEST: "800Mi",
            DEPLOY_MEM_LIMIT  : "800Mi",
            READINESS_DELAY   : 30,
            LIVENESS_DELAY    : 360,
    ]
    prodProjectConfig = [
            NUM_REPLICAS       : 1,
            DEPLOY_CPU_REQUEST : "100m",
            DEPLOY_CPU_LIMIT   : "100m",
            DEPLOY_MEM_REQUEST : "500Mi",
            DEPLOY_MEM_LIMIT   : "500Mi",
            READINESS_DELAY    : 30,
            LIVENESS_DELAY     : 360,
    ]
    gates = [
            integration: false,
            stress     : false,
            acceptance : true,
            production : false
    ]
}
```

Comment: You know what the error means? In any case, please provide a [mcve] so people here can reproduce it.

Comment: I don't think I can reproduce it as it's failing in an Openshift pod. But I can try to grab code from the files where I think the issues are.